# Create-React-Native-App - using native modules

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-ios, create-react-native-app

I have a question related to using native modules with react-native apps.

As described [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#what-are-the-limitations-of-create-react-native-app) it appears that application created with CRNA is not supposed to be used with native modules. Is it still true?

Recently I was able to integrate `@shoutem/ui` module with my app created with CRNA (as far as I understand this is native module because it requires me to run react-native link command) and it was working just fine on my android and ios phones and ios simulator as well.

As [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/15139) PR explains, using react-native link should display error message but I cannot observe it at all.

Has anything changed? This is really confusing. Or maybe my understanding of native modules in react-native is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've imported the fonts used in the toolkit (as described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/262)):

```
async componentWillMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'Rubik-Black': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Black.ttf'),
      'Rubik-BlackItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-BlackItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Bold': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Bold.ttf'),
      'Rubik-BoldItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-BoldItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Italic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Italic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Light': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf'),
      'Rubik-LightItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-LightItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Medium': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf'),
      'Rubik-MediumItalic': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf'),
      'Rubik-Regular': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf'),
      'rubicon-icon-font': require('./node_modules/@shoutem/ui/fonts/rubicon-icon-font.ttf'),
    });

    this.setState({fontsLoaded: true});
  }
```

You shouldn't have issues using Shoutem UI toolkit components.

Fonts are linked into the app's binary and are therefore considered a native dependency.

Comment: Yes, I know. It is working fine for me as well. The problem is that I do not understand why it is working while according to docs is should not?